# Modify kernel scheduler to give longer time slice for particular program

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, ipc

I'm writing a program for the Ubuntu distribution that I want to have larger time slices for when running. I understand that messing with time slices may slow my computers response, but I want my computer to run a dedicated services/processes. Ideally when the parent process is destroyed the scheduler would return to normal. How would I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't just use the built in priority setting tools (i.e. `nice (1)`)?

Comment: I didn't know about the tool.

Comment: Linux also implements a limited "real-time" capacity which will do a bit more than just amping up the process's priority.

Comment: If you only run your server/processes on the box, how will changing any priorities/scheduling/timer parameters change anything?  There is nothing else to run!  Can you not just put in your user manual 'For optimum performance, this server should run on a computer dedicated to it'?

Comment: "_I want to have larger time slices for when running_" why? What is the problem with the default time slice?

Comment: There isn't a problem with the default time slices, its just that I'm dedicating my computer to solve a particular problem that takes a lot of time. Rather than my processor servicing and checking for unnecessary processes or services, I wanted to just dedicate more time for my user space program to run. If I could allot more time, the process will finish faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use **nice(1)** and similar tools for setting process priority - possibly real-time scheduling, but I don't know how well it is implemented in linux.

Positive "Niceness" (upto 20) means lowering priority of the task (and thus less time slices), while negative values (downto -19) make the process more important.

There's also **ionice** for I/O priority which might be of interest depending on use case.

Answer (score 4):

nice will not have any significant effect on the time slice in new versions of Linux (in older versions reducing your priority actually reduced the time slice, just the opposite of what was needed for batch processing).

You can use "schedtool -B PID" (may need to be installed) to set the scheduling policy for one or more PID's to BATCH mode, which increases their time slice from the default value, but also reduces their priority relative to other pids. According to the man entry this can improve performance up to 300% for CPU intensive jobs that are sensitive to cache persistance.

However I have found no way to directly change the default time slice used by the system.